# SQL Server Database Migration Assistant: Cannot connect to server

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a database in-place (same PC) from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2019 Express, by using DMA (Database Migration Assistant). But I cannot connect to the target server (2008) during the "Assessment" task.

I have installed SQL Server 2019 as coexisting installation assigning the following instance names:

- `MSSQLSERVER` (default name assigned during SQL Server 2008 R2 installation)
- `MSSQLSERVER2019` (different instance name assigned during SQL Server 2019 installation)

The PC is named `DESKTOP1` and this results into the following server names:

- `DESKTOP1` for SQL Server 2008 R2
- `DESKTOP1\MSSQLSERVER2019` for SQL Server 2019

Both the server names work fine and I can normally connect to the servers by means of Management Studio.

The weird behaviour is that during the database assessment task, I couldn't connect to the source database server (`DESKTOP1`). Then I tried to go directly to the "Migration" task and I was able to connect. After this I went back to the "Assessment" task and (kind of magic) I was able to connect to the server `DESKTOP1`.

Do you have any clue about this issue? It looks like during Migration task there is something that enable the server connection.

Thank you!

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, you can't directly upgrade from SQL Server 2008 (R2) to SQL Server 2019 on the same host. SQL Server 2008 is not supported on Windows 10/WIndows Server 2016+ where as SQL Server 2019 requires those as a minimum.

Comment: Hello, I do no refer to any upgrade. The question is about Database Migration Assistant. SQL server 2008 is no longer supported but it works fine on Windows 10 and the migration to 2019 works but the Connection to the Server for the Data Assesment requires a workaround (I cannot see the server active so I need to go directly to the data migration task and then go back again to the data assesment). It would be OK but I need to write a manual for the user and would like to solve it without workaround. Thanks